# Yii2 Browser Popup Window Layout duplicating

Tags: yii2

I'm having trouble in overriding the default application theme on a browser popup window.

I am using window.open to create popup window.

```
this is my action
$this->layout = '@app/views/layouts/layout2'; //new layout
echo $this->render('sr_main'); //popup page
```

Now it loads both layouts. "`main`" and "`layout2`".

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXuT5.jpg)

Comment: Can you post some screenshots and view,layout codes ?

Comment: Did you test with renderPartial?

Comment: Yes i use renderPartial its not work to me.